# Laravel Eloquent do multiple counts on a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to do multiple counts on a relationship. I can do 1 using the withCount method and passing it a closure with the condition like so:

```
    $subscribedAudits = Audit::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->where('approved', 1);
    })->withCount(['users' => function($query) {
        $query->where('approved', 0);
    }])->with(['users'])->get();
```

This creates a field on the result called `users_count` with the count of users where approved is = 0. This is the expected result.

Now I want to do a count on another field on the users table but I'm unsure how to work that into the Eloquent query. I tried the following:

```
    $subscribedAudits = Audit::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->where('approved', 1);
    })->withCount(['users' => function($query) {
        $query->where('approved', 0);
    }])->withCount(['users' => function($query) {
        $query->where('viewed', 0);
    }])->with(['users'])->get();
```

This won't work as it can only return 1 attribute named `users_count`.

Is there any way around this without doing another query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple counts to the `withCount` method and give them a custom name like so:

```
Model::withCount([
    'relationship as count_1' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('active', 1);
    },
    'relationship as count_2' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('active', 0);
    }
]);
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
$subscribedAudits = Audit::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->where('approved', 1);
})->withCount([
    'users as disapproved_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('approved', 0);
    },
    'users as not_viewed_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('viewed', 0);
    }
])->with(['users'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions sometimes treated not as expected by Eloquent. I suggest using `selectRaw('count() FILTER (WHERE)')` instead.